# Can GetStringCritical() throw an exception?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In some JNI code we have, we call `GetStringCritical()` to get the contents of a string. Right after, we call `ExceptionCheck()` to deal with any exception that occurred.

I'm running the code with `-Xcheck:jni`, and I'm getting tons of ...

`Warning: Calling other JNI functions in the scope of Get/ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical or Get/ReleaseStringCritical`

... which is being caused by the call to `ExceptionCheck()` (as determined via stepping though the code).

From this, am I correct in assuming that `GetStringCritical()` cannot cause an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringCritical) to the multiple topics that actually contain real information about the `GetStringCritical` function, you find:

> Inside a critical region, native code must not call other JNI
>   functions

and

> Returns a pointer to a Unicode string, or NULL if the operation fails.

So, no, it won't cause an exception and the warning is consistent with the docs: don't call `other JNI functions`.

Calling `GetStringCritical` gives you short term access to the characters in to the string so you can use or copy them with `C` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Main reason is that after you use getstringprimitive/getprimitivearray, you have to call releaseprimitive. If not, when you have more than one call with same java object, it tells that u already open a session for one object already and you try to use it within another function call.

For example:

```
Func1(..){
env->GetStringCritical(..)
env->ReleaseStringCritical(..)
}

Func2(..){
env->GetStringCritical(..)
}
```

When you dont put release one of them, it gives that warning. Just put release to Func2 too and get rid of that problem.